# Why does this Translation of Curl into Python requests fail?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

The following `print` outputs a copy/pastable Curl command which works as expected in my terminal and the server responds with 200:

```
print (
 "curl 'https://some.domain.com/path"
 "?param1=1&param2=2' "
 "-X PUT "
 "-H 'Host: foo.domain.com' "
 "-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0' "
 "-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' "
 "-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' "
 "-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' "
 "-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' "
 "-H 'SomeToken: a16e7f17df3f4bdb982dac9593a941ab' "
 "-H 'Cookie: "
     "cookie1=value1; "
     "' "
 "-H 'Connection: keep-alive' "
 "--data "
 '\'{"name":"blubb_234","someId":1234,"someVal":"...",'
 '"yoyoyo":"","cool":{"id":7},"price":"125.5","currency":"EUR"}\''
)
```

---

The following requests command is as far as I can tell a direct translation of above Curl command. But in this case the server responds with a 500:

```
res = requests.request("PUT",
    ("https://some.domain.com/path"
     "?param1=1&param2=2"),
    headers={
        "Host": "foo.domain.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "SomeToken": "a16e7f17df3f4bdb982dac9593a941ab",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    data={
        "name": "blubb_234",
        "someId": 1234,
        "someVal": "...",
        "yoyoyo": "",
        "cool": {"id":7},
        "price":"125.5",
        "currency":"EUR"
    },
    cookies={"cookie1":"value1"}
)
```

**Any idea what might be wrong?**

---

```
> requests.__version__
2.2.1

> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
```

Comment: I *think* the difference is that your `curl` call is explicitly passing a JSON blob in the body of the request, while your `request.requests` call does not JSON-encode the dictionary you are passing as the `data` argument. Try `requests.request(..., data=json.dumps({...}))`.

Comment: Don't delete.  I'll close it as a duplicate.  Future users will be able to google and be redirected.